# C++ LLVM unique_ptr issue

Tags: c++, llvm, unique-ptr

I honestly have no clue what to do here.
I was following this LLVM tutorial of C++ (https://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/MyFirstLanguageFrontend/LangImpl02.html) when i came across this function:

```
static std::unique_ptr<ExprAST> ParseNumberExpr() {
  auto Result = std::make_unique<NumberExprAST>(NumVal);
  getNextToken(); // consume the number
  return std::move(Result);
}
```

It's giving me an error on the last line of the function that I can't convert a `unique_ptr<NumberExprAST>` to a `unique_ptr<ExprAST>` (NumberExprAST is a child of ExprAST) and I guess the error makes sense, but how is this in the tutorial then? I literally copied the function word-to-word (I even copied the classes nearly word-to-word), yet I'm still getting an error. If anyone else has gone through this tutorial, what did they do in this circumstance?

EDIT: I was requested to show the whole code of the AST file, so here it is:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include "lexer.hpp"

class ExprAST
{
public:
    virtual ~ExprAST() {}
};

class NumExprAST : ExprAST
{
private:
    double m_val;
public:
    NumExprAST(const double val) {m_val = val;}
};

class VarExprAST : ExprAST
{
private:
    std::string m_name;
public:
    VarExprAST(const std::string &name) {m_name = name;}
};

class BinOprExprAST : ExprAST
{
private:
    char m_opr;
    std::unique_ptr<ExprAST> m_lhs, m_rhs;
public:
    BinOprExprAST(char opr, std::unique_ptr<ExprAST> lhs,
                  std::unique_ptr<ExprAST> rhs)
    {
        m_opr = opr;
        m_lhs = std::move(lhs);
        m_rhs = std::move(rhs);
    }
};

class CallExprAST : public ExprAST {
private:
  std::string m_callee;
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<ExprAST>> m_args;
public:
    CallExprAST(const std::string &callee,
                std::vector<std::unique_ptr<ExprAST>> args)
    {
        m_callee = callee;
        m_args = args;
    }
};

class PrototypeAST {
    std::string m_name;
    std::vector<std::string> m_args;

public:
    PrototypeAST(const std::string &name, std::vector<std::string> args)
    {
        m_name = name;
        m_args = args;
    }

    const std::string &getName() const {return m_name;}
};

class FunctionAST {
    std::unique_ptr<PrototypeAST> m_proto;
    std::unique_ptr<ExprAST> m_body;

public:
    FunctionAST(std::unique_ptr<PrototypeAST> proto,
                std::unique_ptr<ExprAST> body)
    {
        m_proto = std::move(proto);
        m_body = std::move(body);
    }
};

static int currTok;
static int getNextToken() {return currTok = getToken();}

std::unique_ptr<ExprAST> logErr(const std::string errStr)
{
    std::cerr << "log error: " << errStr << "\n";
    return nullptr;
}
std::unique_ptr<PrototypeAST> logErrP(const std::string errStr)
{
    logErr(errStr);
    return nullptr;
}

static std::unique_ptr<ExprAST> parseNumExpr()
{
    auto result = std::make_unique<NumExprAST>(g_numVal);
    getNextToken();
    return std::move(result);
}
```

And the error message I'm getting is this:

```
no suitable user-defined conversion from "std::unique_ptr<NumExprAST, std::default_delete<NumExprAST>>" to "std::unique_ptr<ExprAST, std::default_delete<ExprAST>>" exists
```

The error message is coming from VSCode and not the terminal so it may not be exactly like a standard C++ error message.

Comment: I read this tutorial few times, but never done it. But anyway I pasted the code into http://cpp.sh/ and it compiles & run, so the code is correct. (it is possible to convert `unique_ptr<child>` to `unique_ptr<parent>`)

Comment: I'm actually not _too_ experienced with unique pointers but I know their general purpose and how to somewhat use them, but I'll try to find a way to convert the child to the parent. It's really strange that it is working for you and not for me; technically I am actually using VSCode's intellisense to find errors since I can't really test it on anything yet (no main method), but that shouldn't really be an issue. Anyway, ill try and do the chuld to parent thing and get back to this question.

Comment: But you dont have to do that since its implicitly converted. Just like in your code snippet of `ParseNumberExpre()`.  Also if you would show the whole code and the exact error message that would be more informative.

Comment: Code is about 100 lines total but  I'll just upadate the question right now

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 you need to use public inheritance `class NumExprAST : public ExprAST` instead of `class NumExprAST : ExprAST` to make it convertible

Comment: Oh god yes, I'm such an idiot. I don't even know why I forgot about this, I've done inheritance before. Anyway, thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [private inheritance](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/derived_class) (like `class A:B{}` or  `struct A: private B{}`) then you can only do the conversion to the base-class inside the type itself or in a friended function or type.

So if you want `unique_ptr` to be able to do the conversion, it's easiest if you just use public inheritance like

```
class NumExprAST : public ExprAST {
   // ...
}
```